# send/receive thread seems blocked when access serial port

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, uart

I wrote a UART read/write program in C, here is the demo test code,

```c
typedef struct devpara {
  int fd;
  int num
} devpara_t;

int g_step = 1; // init step

int main()
{
    int ret = 0;
    devpara_t *dpara = malloc(sizeof(devpara_t));
    
    dpara->hd = openuart("/ttyS0");  // here, (O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (dpara->hd < 0)
        return -1;
    configuart(dpara->hd, 115200, 8, 1, NOPAR, 1 /* stopbits */);
        
    ret = pthread_create(&wtid, NULL, recvthread, (void *)dpara);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("pthread_create failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ret = pthread_create(&wtid, NULL, sendthread, (void *)dpara);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("pthread_create failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    pthread_join(rtid, NULL);
    pthread_join(wtid, NULL);
    if(dpara->hd >= 0)
        closeuart(dpara->hd);
    if(NULL != dpara)
        free(dpara);
    return ret;
}

void *recvthread(void *para)
{
    unsigned char buf[128] = {0};
    int ret = -1;
    devpara_t *localpara = (devpara_t *)para;

    for (;;) {
        ret = read(localpara->fd, buf, 128);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex);
        switch(g_step) {
        case 1:
            if (!strncmp(buff, "result1", strlen("result1")))
              pthread_cond_signal(&g_cond);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (!strncmp(buff, "result2", strlen("result2")))
              pthread_cond_signal(&g_cond);
            break;
        case 3:
            if (!strncmp(buff, "result3", strlen("result3")))
              pthread_cond_signal(&g_cond);
            break;  
        default:
            break;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex);
    }
}

void *sendthreadfunc(void *para)
{
    FILE *fp;
    devpara_t *localpara = (devpara_t *)para;
    
    for (;;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&g_cond, &g_mutex);
        switch(g_step) {
            case 1:
                printf("1->2");
                senddata(localpara->fd, "test2");
                g_step = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("2->3");
                fp = fopen("test.config", r);
                if (NULL == fp)
                  return NULL;
                g_step = 3;
                break;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex);
}
```

1. recv thread is waiting for data from UART;
2. send thread is going to send data to UART and trigger a response data from UART;

At the very beginning, I triggered the recv thread by sending a "test1" to UART (with other UART tools), so that recv thread will read "result1"; after `printf("2->3");`, I tried to trigger recv thread jump into `case 3:` by sending a "result2" to UART (with other UART tools), however, it failed, and it seems that normal UART tools can not send test string until I quit the main thread.

Is something wrong in thread coding logic?
default uart configuration is as following, others like bdrate/stopbit is configured with parameters.

```
    termios_cfg.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;
    termios_cfg.c_cflag |= CREAD;
    termios_cfg.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    termios_cfg.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    termios_cfg.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
    termios_cfg.c_cc[VMIN]  = 1;
    //flush
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    ret = tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &termios_cfg);
    if (0 != ret) {
        printf("tcsetattr failed!\n");
        ret = -1;
    }
```

Comment: Do your `printf()`:s also go to UART? Do you know what '\n` is for in `printf()` formatting strings?

Comment: What happens if your first call to `read` reads two bytes?

Comment: @0andriy No, in this program, only ```senddata()``` and ```read()``` will write/read data from uart.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz at the first time, I mean, I send a string to uart with a prebuilt uart tools (like supper terminal in windows), then ```read(localpara->fd, buf, 128);``` can get "result1" from uart, just like a response(similar with AT cmd/resp) from uart. completed sequnce is "\r\nresult1\r\n".

Comment: You have not provided a minimal, reproducible example. Apparently you're using Linux? Rather than a "*UART*", your userspace program accesses a **serial terminal**. There's a device driver that buffers all data. See [Linux serial drivers](https://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html). Your problem(s) could be related to termios configuration (e.g. canonical mode), but the code you provided is incomplete. You fail to check the return code from **read()**. What exactly are "*other UART tools"*? The only way to "*send*" data to/from a UART is with a connection to  *another* UART.

Comment: @Rui Sure, you *could* get the full response. But you could also get the first two bytes of the response. Your code would then throw them away and never get the command.

Comment: @sawdust yes, the code logic is PC(Linux) <-->uart <-->device; "other UART tools" is linux tools "minicom", which was installed by ```sudo apt install minicom```, and my program is also a uart application.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz but, even I have added log ```printf("read %d", ret);```, after ```ret = read(localpara->fd, buf, 128);```, there is no print here, both send and receive thread is waiting (or maybe blocked).

Comment: @Rui Do you flush stdout? Because that `printf` doesn't flush anything and just writes to an internal buffer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz there are no`\n`:s there, and OP seems ignores my question.

Comment: @0andriy sorry, misunderstood your comment about '\n'. Here, ```printf()``` is just for printing log msg to stand io, which is cmd terminal in linux side in this case, content in ```printf()``` will not be sent to uart device.

Answer (score 0):

the root cause is found.
read buffer is read and cleaned by another thread(application), also, device did not response sometimes. code logic seems ok.